# Migrate Streams and Tasks (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, development-environment

Is there a way to migrate(Copy) Streams and Task to another account in Snowflake. I can see streams and tasks copied to another DB if I clone a DB within the same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what has to be moved, there is an option to get DDL and run on second environment:

[GET_DDL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html):

> **Returns a DDL statement that can be used to recreate the specified object.** For databases and schemas, GET_DDL is recursive, i.e. it returns the DDL statements for recreating all supported objects within the specified database/schema.

```
-- identifying tasks/streams
SHOW TASKS IN DATABASE ...;
SHOW STREAMS IN DATABASE...;

-- getting DDL for specific task/stream
SELECT GET_DDL('STREAM', <name>);
SELECT GET_DDL('TASK', <name>);
```